# Cannot resolve local Android application crash

Tags: android, adt

I was running my application completely OK, until at some point every time I tried to launch it it gave me this error message:

> "Unfortunately, [app_name] has stopped"
>   whether if it's on the emulator or the device on debugging mode I get the same crash

The manifest.xml:

```
    <activity android:name="com.***.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:noHistory="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file) trace:

```
05-28 14:15:36.127: D/overlay(158): Unset pipe=VG0 dpy=0; Unset pipe=VG1 dpy=0; Unset pipe=RGB1 dpy=0;
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.***.jerusalem/com.***.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.***.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity" on path: /data/app/com.***.jerusalem-1.apk
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.***.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity" on path: /data/app/com.***.jerusalem-1.apk
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-28 14:15:36.127: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):     ... 11 more
05-28 14:15:36.127: W/ActivityManager(525):   Force finishing activity com.***.jerusalem/com.***.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity
```

I checked the build path, reinstalled all the components and even exported the project to another computer, in which it all worked fine, the only thing I know for sure is that it's local, but I can't point it out.

Comment: just try with .SplashScreenActivity in the Manifest

Comment: Great package name you have chosen....!!

Comment: BTW Do you know package name convention exactly?

Comment: I just changed to the ***... corporate rules.. anyway I have found the solution, apparently google has made some changes on sdk rev 22 (see on my answer) @PareshMayani

Answer (score 0):

The presented exception shows as he can't find the Activity at runtime, as how it is declared and called.

Try with:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.***.android"
...

 <activity android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:noHistory="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,
So the problem is with some of the changes on the SDK rev 22..
Given that it's a library project (such as mine), it doesn't recognize the support libraries.
You can check out [this post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=55304) or just follow these steps:

> For all projects (app and library):
>
> 1. Right click the project, and choose Properties
> 2. Go to Java Build Path-Order and Export.
> 3. Tick 'Android Private Libraries'
>      --- (Optional) Clean all projects if necessary

Regards to Nikolay from the referenced post